# Marketing Cloud in Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, community

I have configured Marketing Cloud Connect but i need a Tab of Marketing Cloud in SFDC. I could not find the option to create  it from Setup > Create > Tabs > New.

Anyone is having any idea how can i get a tab?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the link to the steps you followed to install the connector.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_marketing_cloud_connect.htm&type=5